# Select the children of a node from a tree in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I am using the following code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1xm61yg/9/) to display data (in JSON format) by the means of a tree, which work correctly. The goal is that whenever the user double clicks on a node that the following things should happen:

- (1) change the color of the 'selected' node
- (2) change the color of all its children (subtree)

The first goal (1) works correctly. To do so I used the code snippets below:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); }, function(d) { return d.isSelected || (d.isSelected = false); });
```

Every node has a isSelected attribute, which is a sort of a flag. And the color of the node is changed thanks to the next code snippet:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
  .on("click", click)
  .each(function(d)
  {
    var sel = d3.select(this);
    //var state = false;
    sel.on("dblclick", function(e)
    {
        //window.alert("state is: " + state);
        //state = !state;

      if (!e.isSelected) {
        e.isSelected = true;
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("fill", "black");
        //Select all nodes


        selectSubtree(e);

      } else {
        e.isSelected = false;
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("fill", "#fff");

        //deselect all nodes


        deselectSubtree(e);

      }
    });
  });
```

The problem occurs when the 'selected' node is sent to the **selectSubtree(d)** function. I don't know how to exactly change the color of the node. Can someone help me?

```
function selectSubtree(node){

if(node.children){

node.children.forEach(function(d)
{
    //Select all children
  d.isSelected = true;

        selectSubtree(d);
});}}
```

My first attempt was to use **d3.select("#id").select("circle").style("fill", "#fff");** , since every node has an id, but it wasn't working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**STEP 1**

Give unique id to all the circle in your case i am setting the circle's id as the name

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("id", function(d){return d.name})//give ids to circle
      .attr("r", 1e-6);
```

**STEP2**

In `selectsubtree` function make the circle dom fill(with black) by using the id we set in step1

```
function selectSubtree(node)
{
    d3.select("#" + node.name).style("fill", "black");
     //your code of recursively calling  function if it has children.
```

**STEP3**

In `deselectSubtree` function make the circle dom fill(with white) by using the id we set in step1

```
function deselectSubtree(node)
{
    d3.select("#" + node.name).style("fill", "white");
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/m3haL4n8/)